C/CPP calls to an external utility at compile time from a makefile
I need advice on how to call an external program from the makefile to obtain some data and how to sell this data to the program at the time of compilation?
Hi friends. I need each application I build to have its own unique id.
The requirements are:

based on a database
16 bytes
at compile time
unique

I have an id.hpp file with the content:
const uint8_t ID[16] = UNIQUE_ID;

I have a program in python, 'makeid.py' which will generate an id for me. Now I need the make command to call my `makeid.py' program and sell the generated string to this file.
I know how to pass some parameters to the program during build using the -D switch, but I would like to edit the makefile so that it is done automatically, so that it pulls a new id from this program with each assembly.
I read it somewhere once but I don't remember anymore. You certainly know how to do it, Google didn't give me any advice, it just refers to some uuid and nodeid...

How to generate .h header file using makefile and use it in same makefile for compilation of source? has a couple of examples.

@RetiredNinja I tried according to How can I generate a source file during the build but failed. It was constantly missing some delimiter.. Even if I completely copied the entire example or if I wrote one command, still nothing!

Make sure you only use tab characters as leading space in makefiles. Using spaces will cause an error like that.

@RetiredNinja  Thanks. Maybe because..

You said the ID will be 16 bits, but you're providing space for 16 bytes.

@JohnBollinger What do you mean? Did I not include parentheses? UNIQUE_ID is a 16-character string. E.g 16 bytes: ID[16] = {"1234567890abcdef"}

John means that in your requirements list above you said 16 bits.  There are 8 bits to a byte, so 16 bits is 2 bytes.  But you allocated space for 16 bytes, which is 16 * 8 = 128 bits.  I presume that you mistyped your question and you really meant that the requirement is 16 bytes, not 16 bits.

Edited. Than you

Since you didn't actually show us how your makefile currently works we can't provide you with an answer based on your implementation.
So, I'll just say you can do something like this:
CPPFLAGS += -DUNIQUE_ID="$$(makeid.py)"

and that will do it, assuming that the makeid.py program prints the ID to stdout without any "extra" text, that you are building C++ code, and that your compile rules use the standard variables in the normal ways.

Yes, that's what I did just now CPPFLAGS += -DUNIQUE_ID=\"$(makeid.py)\" In parentheses because it must be a string.
But I tried to use add_custom_command, I'm trying to build a project for esp-idf but it still didn't work. But that will probably be a question elsewhere.

Why did you choose two $$ characters: CPPFLAGS += -DUNIQUE_ID="$$(makeid.py)"? Me works with one: CPPFLAGS += -DUNIQUE_ID=\"$(makeid.py)\". :-O

@PetrovichDenis I think MadScientist meant for the line to go into a makefile since that's what your question says. In that case it won't work with a single $. With a single $ it'll expand the makefile macro makeid.py which is likely not set so you'll get an empty string.

@PetrovichDenis, add_custom_command is a CMake thing, and you didn't previously say a single word about  CMake (which is an altogether separate thing from make).  If you're trying to write CMake instructions then the question is grossly misleading.  If not, then add_custom_command is irrelevant.

This is why I suggested you provide some actual examples of what you've tried to do.  If you had done that we could see whether what you're doing is writing a makefile or writing a CMakeLists.txt file.  These are, as John points out, completely different things.

I think it's be a cmake. I wrote that into component.mk file. :o :/

You should definitely know which tools you are using.  If you have to run cmake before you run make then you are working with cmake and cmake files and all the information provided here is wrong or useless, because you say in your question you are writing makefiles but you are not.  It's irrelevant how to code this in make, because cmake will generate your makefiles completely so you can't "embed" makefile structures into a cmake file.  You should rewrite your question or ask a new question making clear you're using cmake and use the cmake tag, not the makefile tag.

@MadScientist I call make in the terminal. This is ESP-IDF. My English is not very good to understand everything. Some things in the documentation are incomprehensible to me and others don't work. :(

The question isn't whether you call make.  The question is whether before you call make, you have to run cmake first.  cmake is a tool that creates makefiles (or other types of project build files, such as ninja or Visual Studio project files).  If you have to run cmake fist, then nothing you write in a makefile is used because cmake will regenerate your makefiles from scratch every time you run it.  If you use cmake you have to figure out how to get cmake to perform this operation which is a completely different thing than getting a makefile to perform it.

@MadScientist I use ESP-IDF. He uses cmake internally. I just call cmake menuconfig and cmake. But I need to transfer one definition to the program from the outside during compilation, so that I call another program that generates the data for me. In other words, I need to call another program from, probably from cmake, which does something and returns something.

I have no idea what ESP-IDF is, but as above if you run cmake then you're using cmake, and your question has to be clear that you need a solution that works with cmake not make: you should edit it to make that clear and remove the makefile tag from your question and add in cmake instead.

After reading a few comments here, I dug into it again and came up with this:

It's not make but cmake

And I solved it like this:
makeid_path := $(dir $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))tools/makeid.py
UNIQUE_ID := "$(shell ${makeid_path})"
src/acl_id.o: CPPFLAGS += -DUNIQUE_ID=\"${UNIQUE_ID}\"

Where
makeid_path := $(dir $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))tools/makeid.py obtained absolute paths to the 'makeid.py' utility,
Line UNIQUE_ID := "$(shell ${makeid_path})" call the utility
And src/acl_id.o: CPPFLAGS += -DUNIQUE_ID=\"${UNIQUE_ID}\" inserts the obtained data into the source file.
Sure, it didn't solve my problem, but it will do for the time being.

None of the above is valid cmake syntax, so I don't know where you put this text or how you used it but you should be careful because if you edited any of the makefiles that cmake generated to add this text then the next time you run cmake all your changes will be deleted.

@MadScientist I know what you mean.I don't edit the file generated by cmake.ESP-IDF uses two variants of the cmake file as I understand it.CMakeLists.txt and component.mk and that's exactly what I don't understand.When I fill in everything(paths, flags) in CMakeLists.txt it doesn't work,it can't find sources.When I fill in everything in component.mk, it works,but I don't have the environment variables available.The ESP-IDF documentation,they write about how to work with CMakeLists.txt,but none of the settings in it work and have no effect on the compilation process. I'm Deer from it.

Actually, in reality, I need to somehow write 16 bytes of data (16x1-bit numbers) to a specific place in the microprocessor's memory after the main program is loaded into it. And in addition so that the uploaded data is incremented by 1 with every other MCU.
